# Real image of virtual object

Tags: geometric-optics

Are real images always inverted, even for a virtual object? I tried to make ray diagrams for such a situation in concave mirror, I am getting a real but erect and diminished image between pole and focus. Also, can I use the reversibility of path here? As when we take a real object between focus and pole we get a virtual, erect and enlarged image. I tried using this, by reversing the paths of light then also I am getting the same result. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you’re not going wrong anywhere. A real image of a virtual object will not be inverted, just as a virtual image of a real object will not be inverted. Inversion occurs when the object and image are both real or both virtual.